# Video can't press play on React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a working product that takes a file from API and read as a blob. But pressing the play button on the video does not work. I have tried using  tried using querySelector or a useState variable. All not working.

It can read a local file but not from the API.

```
const [outputImg, setOutputImg] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
    getOutput()
    
}, [])
    
async function getOutput() {
    await axios.get("/output-image", {responseType: "blob"})
      .then((response) => {
         var imageUrl = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(response.data);
         setOutputImg(imageUrl);
         var vid = document.querySelector(".img1")
         console.log(response)
     })
    
     console.log("Output image", outputImg)
}
```

HTML section

```
<video src={outputImg} className="img1 video-js vjs-default-skin" style={{position: "absolute"}}autoPlay controls preload="auto" width="100%" height="100%" data-setup='{"textTrackSettings": false}'/>
```

[Data type log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0tGQ.png)

[Fetching method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4liCG.png)

[Video tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SF2M1.png)

[Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkXAA.png)

Comment: Please include the relevant details as text in your question - images makes the question hard to search for, don't allow for copy and pasting, are inaccessible to those that have trouble seeing og reading, and requires the answerer to move between multiple sets of content when trying to parse your complete question. I'm not sure how this is related to FastAPI?

Comment: Hello. Thanks for responding. I have just did the edits.